# How to use the new URLConnection for Urlshortner in android

Tags: android, apache, httpclient, httpurlconnection, google-url-shortener

i am trying to change  HTTPClient deprecated  code but i get i/o exception always and i dont know where i am wrong.
**my old deprecated  code snippt**

```
  public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String address, String longUrl) {
     // Making HTTP request
     try {
        // DefaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(address);

        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity("{\"longUrl\":\"" + longUrl + "\"}"));
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

**my new not working code snippt**

```
 try {
    HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) ((new          URL(address).openConnection()));
    httpcon.setDoOutput(true);
    httpcon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpcon.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpcon.connect();

 //   byte[] outputBytes = "{'value': 7.5}".getBytes("UTF-8");
   is = httpcon.getInputStream();
 /*   os.write(outputBytes);

    os.close();*/
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to send your parameter value to the URL, which you are not sending yet.

```
 OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(--SENDING PARAMETER HERE--);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            out.close();
```

Then next, use bufferedReader to get response:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

And receive the response as follows:

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
{
    Log.d("finalResponse: ", inputLine);
}
```

Set the inputLine data type to the data type of your response. Make sure the parameter you are sending is exactly in the form the API/URL is set up to receive it as.

And yes, don't forget to close the BufferedReading and disconnect URLConnection.

```
in.close();
httpcon.disconnect();
```

I hope this helps. Happy Coding.

Comment: i have one more doubt MultipartEntityBuilder multiPartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
                multiPartEntityBuilder.addPart("uploadedfile1", bin);
                multiPartEntityBuilder.addPart("inviteId", new StringBody(inviteIdArrayList.get(0).toString(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                post.setEntity(multiPartEntityBuilder.build());  in this case how to set setEntity  work?       whats changes for set multiPartEntityBuilder.build()           OutputStream  allow only string